# Button click not hitting OnPost() method when ENTER is hit

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm implementing a Form on ASP.NET Core Razor Page. The problem is `OnPost()` method is being hit on enter keypress (That is Only when we first click on `GName` Input field and the cursor start blinking and then we press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and not hitting on button click.

Here is the `.cshtml` file `<Form>` code:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label lead text-center" asp-for="GName">
                Enter A Name To Create Greetings
            </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-signature fa-1x"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input required type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase" asp-for="GName" class="form-control" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create Greetings</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the `OnPost()` method from `PageModel`:

```
[BindProperty]
public string GName { get; set; }
 
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return GName != null ? RedirectToPage("./SelectGreetings", new { gname = GName }) : (IActionResult)Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button type to `submit` to perform the form submission:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create Greetings</button>
```

[Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)